# GridView HeaderText is empty in some cases

Tags: .net, asp.net

It returns an empty string!

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%= "2323" %>'>
```

How to solve it? Originally i want to invoke a page method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using HeaderTemplate solved my problem, but it doesn't explain why. :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="2323">
```

UPDATE:

Remove the HeaderTemplate tags and try doing it programmatically:

http://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/615373-setting-text-headertemplate-how

Comment: i need something like this: <%= GetHeaderText() %>

Comment: I'm updating the answer but it's hard to know exactly what you're trying to do from the question...